# Nodejs winston session id logging

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using winston with node & express & can't find a suitable way to simply augment all log entries with express's session.id (via an extensive google & SO search) - any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answer vesse, I need it slightly more general than that though - ie. wherever I call winston, not just morgan request logging. I've overridden winston.log so I can call log.info(req, message), or log.warn etc and the session id is passed to the meta info from the req. I'm also using cookie-session which doesnt create the session id for me, so my solution is:

```
var CustomLogger = function(options){
    CustomLogger.super_.apply(this, arguments);
}
util.inherits(CustomLogger, winston.Logger);

CustomLogger.prototype.log = function () {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    var req = args[1];
    if (req.session) {
        req.session.id = req.session.id || uuid.v4();
        var meta = _.merge((args[3] || {}), {sessionId: req.session.id});
        CustomLogger.super_.prototype.log.call(this, args[0], args[2] + ' | ', meta);
    }
    else {
        // no req.session, assume req hasnt been passed in as 1st param
        CustomLogger.super_.prototype.log.apply(this, arguments);
    }
}

var logger = new CustomLogger({
    transports: [ ... ],
    exitOnError: false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For Express request logs you could do:

```
var morgan  = require('morgan'),
    winston = require('winston');
// Define a new format token
morgan.token('id', function(req, res) {
  return req.session ? req.session.id : 'N/A';
});
// Create a stream using Winston for logging
var winstonStream = {
  write: function(msg, encoding) {
    winston.info(msg);
  }
};
// Create a logger middleware that uses the new token in format
// and writes to Winston logging stream
var expressLogger = morgan(morgan.combined + ' - :id', { stream: winstonStream });

app.use(expressLogger);
```

Don't know how you could achieve the same for every `winston[level]()` call as you do need to have the request object at hand (apart from passing the object around to every bit of code).